# Jssor blurred/pixelated text in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, slider

I've been experimenting with [Jssor](http://www.jssor.com). When I add the [responsive code](http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-make-responsive-slider.html) to the [tab slider demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html) I see the tab labels get pixelated as the viewport size increases. I also see this effect with the [image gallery demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html) when I replace the thumbnail with text, eg:

Replace:

```
<img u="thumb" src="../img/landscape/thumb-01.jpg" />
```

with:

```
<div u="thumb"><p style="text-align:center;">Slide1</p></div>
```

There are [screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsvUk.jpg). I also see the effect with caption text (as shown in the last screenshot in the list).

I've looked through the docs and guess I may be missing something. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you create a slider and scales it to bigger size.
That's why text looks blurry in safari.

To fix it, you can create a bigger slider and scales it to smaller size.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... and for a great slider :) I've changed the widths and heights to:

    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 1024px; height: 623px;">

    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 512px; overflow: hidden;">

    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort05" style="position: absolute; width: 924px; height: 80px; left:50px; bottom: 20px;">

and I still see the blur on the thumbnail text. There's a screenshot with the viewport at 600px and 1024px [here](http://imgur.com/a/oRBlJ).

Comment: It is probably caused by how the method `$SetScaleWidth()` is implemented. It seems to set a 'scale(x)` style on the container insted of updating all the css `width', 'height', etc. properties set by the plugin for each slide. When the scale factor becomes bigger than 1, texts and images looks blurred. For a real responsive slider, the sizes of all the slides components should be defined in percentage but, at this time, jssor plugin does not allow that.